# How to serialize all data in html form

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing routine form submission in html and for some reason this time it is not working at all.

I have put together quick fiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/qrfoanh2/ ) :

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#formy').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $('#formy').serialize();
        $(".miejsce").html(data);

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formy">
   <div class="form-group row">
     <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
     </div>
   </div>
    <div class="row">
      <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Radios</legend>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios1" value="option1" checked>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">Reset zegara odblokowania dni</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios2" value="option2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">Edycja dni subskrypcji</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
     <div class="col-sm-10">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="action();"> - GO : GO - </button>
     </div>
   </div>
</form>

<div class="miejsce" style="background:#ddd;width:100%;height:200px;"></div>
```

I would like to serialize form data, but for some reason i only get radio box information and never data from text input field with email. Please help

Comment: try adding "name" property to your form elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your input[type="email"] tag a *name* attribute. Form inputs are referenced by name in the request when the form is submitted.

```
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
```

I updated the fiddle you have posted.